# Attribute Error: type object 'StartPage' has no attribute 'Username_Text'

Tags: python

I’m trying to call as stringvar out of another class but get the following error :

`AttributeError: type object 'class' has no attribute 'stringVar'`

Please see the code below, I don’t know what I’m doing wrong.

If I add this to my code

```
StartPage_object = StartPage()

USER = StartPage_object.Username_Text.get()
PASSWORD = StartPage_object.Password_Text.get()
```

it gives me a new error:

`__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'parent' and 'controller'`

And If I add this

```
StartPage_object = StartPage(self)

USER = StartPage_object.Username_Text.get()
PASSWORD = StartPage_object.Password_Text.get()
```

it gives me a new error:

`name 'self' is not defined`

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
         tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

#=============Set_Background==================>
     load1 = Image.open(Image_File +"\Login_Bcakground.png")
     render1 =ImageTk.PhotoImage(load1)

#========= Reset_username & Password ===========>
     Username_Text= tk.StringVar()
     Password_Text= tk.StringVar()

#==== Creating Buttons, Entry Box and Labels with there commands ========>

     Login_button = tk.Button(self, text="Login", 
                   fg="#d0cece",bg="#3f9a84",borderwidth = 0, 
                   font=Normal_Text,height =1,width = 10,
                            command=lambda: Login_Check())
     Login_button.place(x=1010,y=380)


     User_Name_Entry = tk.Entry(self,textvariable = Username_Text, fg = 
                        Entry_Box_Text_Colour,bg = 
                        Entry_Box_Back_White,borderwidth = 0, 
                        font=Normal_Text,width = 30)
     User_Name_Entry.place(x=795,y=282)

     User_Pass_Entry = tk.Entry(self,textvariable = Password_Text, fg = 
                       Entry_Box_Text_Colour,bg = 
                       Entry_Box_Back_White,borderwidth = 0, 
                       font=Normal_Text,width = 30)
     User_Pass_Entry.place(x=795,y=329)

#===============Login==========================Login====================>
```

Next Code is not in a class want to make n a globule var

```
USER = StartPage.Username_Text.get()
PASSWORD = StartPage.Password_Text.get()
```

Comment: You've defined a constructor with two parameters and aren't giving it two parameters…

Comment: `StartPage` expects two parameters, `parent` and `controller`, you would need to pass those two values when you create it, e.g. `StartPage(parent, controller)`.

Comment: Do you mean this? ```StartPage_object = StartPage(parent, controller)

USER = StartPage_object.Username_Text.get()
PASSWORD = StartPage_object.Password_Text.get()``` My apologizes, Im still new in coding'with python

Comment: The same error still appears..